# Django REST Framework returns Web API html to POST from app

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am making a POST request from my Angular 2 app to my Django REST Framework API. It seems to work ok but when I look at the returned data in my app it consists of unexpected html as follows (dumped as shown in the alert used to show the data):

```html
{"_body":"\n\n\n\n<!DOCTYPE html>\n<html>\n<head>\n  \n\n    \n      <meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html; charset=utf-8\"/>\n      <meta name=\"robots\" content=\"NONE,NOARCHIVE\" />\n    \n\n    <title>Item List – Django REST framework</title>\n\n    \n      \n        <link rel=\"stylesheet\" type=\"text/css\" href=\"/static/rest_framework/css/bootstrap.min.css\"/>\n        <link rel=\"stylesheet\" type=\"text/css\" href=\"/static/rest_framework/css/bootstrap-tweaks.css\"/>\n      \n\n      <link rel=\"stylesheet\" type=\"text/css\" href=\"/static/rest_framework/css/prettify.css\"/>\n      <link rel=\"stylesheet\" type=\"text/css\" href=\"/static/rest_framework/css/default.css\"/>\n    \n\n  \n</head>\n\n\n<body class=\"\">\n\n  <div class=\"wrapper\">\n    \n      <div class=\"navbar navbar-static-top navbar-inverse\">\n        <div class=\"container\">\n          <span>\n            \n              <a class='navbar-brand' rel=\"nofollow\" href='http://www.django-rest-framework.org'>\n                  Django REST framework\n              </a>\n            \n          </span>\n          <ul class=\"nav navbar-nav pull-right\">\n            \n              \n                \n              \n            \n          </ul>\n        </div>\n      </div>\n    \n\n    <div class=\"container\">\n      \n        <ul class=\"breadcrumb\">\n          \n            \n              <li><a href=\"/api/\">Api Root</a></li>\n            \n          \n            \n              <li class=\"active\"><a href=\"/api/items/\">Item List</a></li>\n            \n          \n        </ul>\n      \n\n      <!-- Content -->\n      <div id=\"content\">\n\n        \n          <form id=\"get-form\" class=\"pull-right\">\n            <fieldset>\n              \n                <div class=\"btn-group format-selection\">\n                  <a class=\"btn btn-primary js-tooltip\" href=\"/api/items/\" rel=\"nofollow\" title=\"Make a GET request on the Item List resource\">GET</a>\n\n                  <button class=\"btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle js-tooltip\" data-toggle=\"dropdown\" title=\"Specify a format for the GET request\">\n                    <span class=\"caret\"></span>\n                  </button>\n                  <ul class=\"dropdown-menu\">\n                    \n                      <li>\n                        <a class=\"js-tooltip format-option\" href=\"/api/items/?format=json\" rel=\"nofollow\" title=\"Make a GET request on the Item List resource with the format set to `json`\">json</a>\n                      </li>\n                    \n                      <li>\n                        <a class=\"js-tooltip format-option\" href=\"/api/items/?format=api\" rel=\"nofollow\" title=\"Make a GET request on the Item List resource with the format set to `api`\">api</a>\n                      </li>\n                    \n                  </ul>\n                </div>\n              \n            </fieldset>\n          </form>\n        \n\n        \n          <form class=\"button-form\" action=\"/api/items/\" data-method=\"OPTIONS\">\n            <button class=\"btn btn-primary js-tooltip\" title=\"Make an OPTIONS request on the Item List resource\">OPTIONS</button>\n          </form>\n        \n\n        \n\n        \n\n          <div class=\"content-main\">\n            <div class=\"page-header\">\n                <h1>Item List</h1>\n            </div>\n            <div style=\"float:left\">\n              \n                \n              \n            </div>\n\n            \n\n            <div class=\"request-info\" style=\"clear: both\" >\n              <pre class=\"prettyprint\"><b>POST</b> /api/items/</pre>\n            </div>\n\n            <div class=\"response-info\">\n              <pre class=\"prettyprint\"><span class=\"meta nocode\"><b>HTTP 201 Created</b>\n<b>Allow:</b> <span class=\"lit\">GET, POST, HEAD, OPTIONS</span>\n<b>Content-Type:</b> <span class=\"lit\">application/json</span>\n<b>Location:</b> <span class=\"lit\">fred</span>\n<b>Vary:</b> <span class=\"lit\">Accept</span>\n\n</span>{\n    &quot;url&quot;: &quot;fred&quot;,\n    &quot;item_type&quot;: &quot;P&quot;,\n    &quot;title&quot;: &quot;&quot;,\n    &quot;credits_applied&quot;: 10,\n    &quot;credits_left&quot;: 10,\n    &quot;credits_gifted&quot;: 0,\n    &quot;username&quot;: &quot;admin&quot;,\n    &quot;liked&quot;: 0,\n    &quot;disliked&quot;: 0\n}</pre>\n            </div>\n          </div>\n\n          \n\n            \n              <div class=\"tabbable\">\n                \n                  <ul class=\"nav nav-tabs form-switcher\">\n                    <li>\n                      <a name='html-tab' href=\"#post-object-form\" data-toggle=\"tab\">HTML form</a>\n                    </li>\n                    <li>\n                      <a name='raw-tab' href=\"#post-generic-content-form\" data-toggle=\"tab\">Raw data</a>\n                    </li>\n                  </ul>\n                \n\n                <div class=\"well tab-content\">\n                  \n                    <div class=\"tab-pane\" id=\"post-object-form\">\n                      \n                        <form action=\"/api/items/\" method=\"POST\" enctype=\"multipart/form-data\" class=\"form-horizontal\" novalidate>\n                          <fieldset>\n                            <input type='hidden' name='csrfmiddlewaretoken' value='Z42Ygso019oegnf1NPdnCeq6ZoqlyWQN' />\n                            \n\n  \n    <div class=\"form-group \">\n  \n    <label class=\"col-sm-2 control-label \">\n      Url\n    </label>\n  \n\n  <div class=\"col-sm-10\">\n    <input name=\"url\" class=\"form-control\" type=\"text\"  value=\"fred\">\n\n    \n\n    \n  </div>\n</div>\n\n  \n\n  \n    <div class=\"form-group\">\n  \n    <label class=\"col-sm-2 control-label \">\n      Item type\n    </label>\n  \n\n  <div class=\"col-sm-10\">\n    <select class=\"form-control\" name=\"item_type\">\n      \n      \n          \n            <option value=\"V\"  >Vine</option>\n          \n      \n          \n            <option value=\"Y\"  >YouTube</option>\n          \n      \n          \n            <option value=\"P\" selected >Photo</option>\n          \n      \n          \n            <option value=\"F\"  >Flickr</option>\n          \n      \n          \n            <option value=\"I\"  >Instagram</option>\n          \n      \n          \n            <option value=\"D\"  >DeviantArt</option>\n          \n      \n          \n            <option value=\"5\"  >500px</option>\n          \n      \n    </select>\n\n    \n\n    \n  </div>\n</div>\n\n  \n\n  \n    <div class=\"form-group \">\n  \n    <label class=\"col-sm-2 control-label \">\n      Title\n    </label>\n  \n\n  <div class=\"col-sm-10\">\n    <input name=\"title\" class=\"form-control\" type=\"text\"  >\n\n    \n\n    \n  </div>\n</div>\n\n  \n\n  \n    <div class=\"form-group \">\n  \n    <label class=\"col-sm-2 control-label \">\n      Credits applied\n    </label>\n  \n\n  <div class=\"col-sm-10\">\n    <input name=\"credits_applied\" class=\"form-control\" type=\"number\"  value=\"10\">\n\n    \n\n    \n      <span class=\"help-block\">Total number of credits applied to this item including any given by VeeU admin</span>\n    \n  </div>\n</div>\n\n  \n\n  \n    <div class=\"form-group \">\n  \n    <label class=\"col-sm-2 control-label \">\n      Credits left\n    </label>\n  \n\n  <div class=\"col-sm-10\">\n    <input name=\"credits_left\" class=\"form-control\" type=\"number\"  value=\"10\">\n\n    \n\n    \n      <span class=\"help-block\">The number of credits still remaining to show the item</span>\n    \n  </div>\n</div>\n\n  \n\n  \n    <div class=\"form-group \">\n  \n    <label class=\"col-sm-2 control-label \">\n      Credits gifted\n    </label>\n  \n\n  <div class=\"col-sm-10\">\n    <input name=\"credits_gifted\" class=\"form-control\" type=\"number\"  value=\"0\">\n\n    \n\n    \n      <span class=\"help-block\">The number of credits this item has been gifted by other users</span>\n    \n  </div>\n</div>\n\n  \n\n  \n\n  \n    <div class=\"form-group \">\n  \n    <label class=\"col-sm-2 control-label \">\n      Liked\n    </label>\n  \n\n  <div class=\"col-sm-10\">\n    <input name=\"liked\" class=\"form-control\" type=\"number\"  value=\"0\">\n\n    \n\n    \n  </div>\n</div>\n\n  \n\n  \n    <div class=\"form-group \">\n  \n    <label class=\"col-sm-2 control-label \">\n      Disliked\n    </label>\n  \n\n  <div class=\"col-sm-10\">\n    <input name=\"disliked\" class=\"form-control\" type=\"number\"  value=\"0\">\n\n    \n\n    \n  </div>\n</div>\n\n  \n\n\n                            <div class=\"form-actions\">\n                              <button class=\"btn btn-primary\" title=\"Make a POST request on the Item List resource\">POST</button>\n                            </div>\n                          </fieldset>\n                        </form>\n                      \n                    </div>\n                  \n\n                  <div class=\"tab-pane\" id=\"post-generic-content-form\">\n                    \n                      <form action=\"/api/items/\" method=\"POST\" class=\"form-horizontal\">\n                        <fieldset>\n                          \n\n\n  <div class=\"form-group\">\n    <label for=\"id__content_type\" class=\"col-sm-2 control-label\">Media type:</label>\n    <div class=\"col-sm-10\">\n      <select data-override=\"content-type\" id=\"id__content_type\" name=\"_content_type\" class=\"form-control\">\n<option value=\"application/json\" selected=\"selected\">application/json</option>\n<option value=\"application/x-www-form-urlencoded\">application/x-www-form-urlencoded</option>\n<option value=\"multipart/form-data\">multipart/form-data</option>\n</select>\n      <span class=\"help-block\"></span>\n    </div>\n  </div>\n\n  <div class=\"form-group\">\n    <label for=\"id__content\" class=\"col-sm-2 control-label\">Content:</label>
```

Clearly I am doing something wrong with my view and serializer but can't see what.

The view is:

```js
class ItemViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Item.objects.all().order_by('-date_added')
    serializer_class = ItemSerializer

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        creator = User.objects.get(pk=self.request.data['owner_id'])
        serializer.save(owner=creator)

    def get_queryset(self):
        this_user = self.request.query_params.get('user', None)
        restrict_to_items_from_user_id = self.request.query_params.get('from', None)
        quantity = self.request.query_params.get('num', 20)

        if restrict_to_items_from_user_id is not None:
            
            queryset = Item.objects.filter(owner=restrict_to_items_from_user_id, active=True).order_by('-date_added')[0:int(quantity)]
        elif this_user is not None:
            
            queryset = Item.objects.filter(active=True, credits_left__gt=0).exclude(pk__in=Seen.objects.filter(user_id=this_user).values_list('item_id', flat=True))[0:int(quantity)]
        else:
            
            queryset = Item.objects.filter(active=True, credits_left__gt=0)[0:int(quantity)]


        return queryset
```

The serializer is:

```js
class ItemSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    username = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    def get_username(self, obj):
        """
        Note that query params can be accessed here as follows:
        request = self.context['request']
        print request.query_params.get['fields']
        """
        value = str(obj.owner)
        return value

    def get_keywords(self, obj):
        value = str(obj.keywords)
        return value

    class Meta:
        model = Item
        fields = ('url', 'item_type', 'title', 'credits_applied', 'credits_left', 'credits_gifted', 'username', 'liked', 'disliked')
```

The API code does what I expect when issuing a GET from my app but I can't see why the POST is returning a whole bunch of unexpected HTML.

Put another way, how can I determine what is returned by the view/serializer after a POST. I might for example want to add some data about bad arguments etc.

**EDIT:**
Here is the Angular 2 code for the POST

```js
    let body = JSON.stringify({ url: 'fred', item_type: 'P', owner_id: 2, owner: "admin" });

    let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');

    this.http.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/items/',
        body, {
        headers: headers
      })
      .subscribe(
        data => {
          alert('DATA RETURNED: '+JSON.stringify(data));
        },
        err => alert('POST ERROR: '+err.json().message),
        () => alert('POST Complete')
      );
```

Comment: One this I can be sure of is that it is rendering Web browsable API, for the endpoint.

Comment: Yes that is what it looks to me too. Any idea why it should be rendering the browsable api?

Comment: Can I see your POST script from Angular2. Because it seems like you are POSTing it directly from HTML form not from API calling.

Comment: I have added the Angular 2 code for the POST to my question

Comment: Also amended title of posting to more accurately reflect the problem

Answer (score 0):

Problem was due to the test app running on the same server as the Django code causing Django to think the Web API was wanted!